# why my training trend is a straight line?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am training a Convolutional nerual network by using tensorboard to record the training trend.

[image]  [image]

And the result seems like a little wird cause it's most a straight line, though in my mind it should like a `log`curve.

Here's some reason fot this but I am not really sure.

- small dataset: I get 10 class and the size of training set is 432 images whose shape is (256, 512). Though I have already done some augmentation work
- shallow network: cause I'm at home where I only have a GPU with 2GB memory.So the network only have 4 convolutional layer and 2 FN layer.(yep curse for virus, pray for china!)

So anyone can tell me the reason for this? And How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe you should just train a little longer? The model clearly hasn't converged yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @xdurch0 's advice.

the reason that I get the result before is I didn't set the right training epoch which is too samll(though I already trained 128 epochs)

Now I post a graph the including two training records to approve of the reason.

**IN ADDITION** It should be very cautious when using `keras.callbacks.EealyStopping` cause we can see the training trend is a complex zip-zap. otherwise we will stop too early or too later.

[image]